# What should I call a place that sells "street food"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Today I went sightseeing in my city. After I got home I wrote the diary in English, but I didn't know what to call a place that sells "street food". Should I call it restaurant, cafe or something else?

**Street food:**
[image: Street food]

**Update**
From [Marcin's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51425/98), I searched each words in his/her answer to find out how to call each type of place that sells food.

**Food stall**
[image: Food stall]

**Food cart**
[image: Food cart]

**Food van** (I'm not sure I can call it "Food van" or not, please correct me if I'm wrong)
[image: Food van]

Comment: You could call it a [snack bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snack_bar)

Comment: We honestly don't have anything -quite- like that in America. So, I'm not sure we have a specific word for it.

Comment: Food vans and lunch vans are making a comeback in America; even in smaller cities like the one I live in there are Salvadorean, Mexican, Thai, and local barbecue vans around.

Comment: Around here these are generally referred to as _salmonella vans_.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer depends on the physical nature of what the place is - it might be a stall, a cart, a van, or something else.

In the case of the sellers pictured, they are located at what appears to be a stall (a table on the street), or a cart (it looks like it has wheels).

Edit: In the US, a van that sells food is idiomatically referred to as a "food truck". You will no doubt be understood elsewhere if you use that expression, but in the UK, without the "food" qualifier, a "truck" and "van" are not the same thing.

Comment: I agree: I would call the pictured item a "*food cart*". (In the US at least, a vehicle that sells food is often colloquially or "affectionately" known as a *roach coach*, but I've only seen that applied to a van, i.e. a vehicle where the seller stands *inside* it and dispenses food out a window.)

Comment: This answer sounds like the right answer for the words of the question. But the picture does not look like a temporary stall, cart, or van. In fact it looks like it is associated with the restaurant and tables directly behind it.

Comment: 'Cart' implies something that can be rolled away, which this doesn't look like (though the wheel in the left may prove me wrong). I would go with 'stall' or 'stand'.

Comment: This brings up the issue that you may need to distinguish between a restaurant that has a building with indoor dining but that puts a table or stall out front as an alternative to inside dining or for a special event, as contrasted with a vendor who ONLY has a stall on the sidewalk. In America, we'd call the first "a restaurant with an outside stall", and only the second would be considered a street vendor.

Comment: @Jay: I have never found the need to explicitly draw this distinction. In fact, I would suggest it does not exist - if you are selling street food on the street, you are a street vendor, whether or not you have a kitchen and restaurant nearby.

Comment: @Marcin the distinction does exist.  Many high end restaurants offer seating outside.  Some call it "dining al fresco".  They are hardly street venders.  They aren't even licensed as such.   If you're going to be literal about it then the only street vender is the guy who sells you oranges while you're stuck in traffic because he actually is standing in the street.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Selling food on a terrace is not selling it on the street.

Comment: @Marcin A truck and a van aren't usually the same thing in the US, either, though the most common type of vehicle used for this purpose (which is otherwise rare) could probably be called either. The popularity of the phrase "food truck" is probably because 1) as often as not, they're either the separate-cab vehicles we normally call trucks or a food cart towed by one; 2) the most common type in many areas is a "taco truck", and "taco van" just wouldn't have the same ring to it.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the generic term, "*vendor*". I am not sure to what extent this word refers to the physical place, but to me it does as much as the word "store" refers to the building as much as the abstract entity.

Comment: Agreed, may prefix it with [type of item sold]. Example [Dumpling] Vendor. If you wanted to get even more specific, you could simply pad the definition with more information, e.g. "The dumpling vendor on X street in Y prefecture.", though that may be a little verbose...

Comment: To modify Moo's idea a little bit: I would be comfortable calling the folks in the picture *street food vendors*, and I am quite confident that people reading it will understand, especially if they know this is in an Asian city and have seen such vendors before.

Answer (score 6):

People who sell things on the street like that are often called "street vendors" whether they have a stall, a cart, etc. I don't know a term specifically for someone selling FOOD on the street.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to say in your diary:

> Today I went to local [street food market](http://www.google.ca/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=936&btnG=Search%20Images&gbv=2&oq=street%20food%20market%20&aq=f&aqi=g-S1g-mS2&gs_upl=804l6265l0l8258l19l18l0l1l1l0l267l3156l0.9.8l17l0&q=street%20food%20market&orq=street%20food%20market%20) with my friends. We grabbed some yummy food at one of the [street food stands](https://www.google.com/search?q=street%20food%20stands&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=wXs&channel=fs&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=_17mTo3NCIGNigL1vundBg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=936) or [street food stalls](https://www.google.com/search?q=street%20food%20stands&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=wXs&channel=fs&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=_17mTo3NCIGNigL1vundBg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=936#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=xXs&channel=fs&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=street%20food%20stalls&pbx=1&oq=street%20food%20stalls&aq=f&aqi=g1g-mS1&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=20188l21366l0l23179l6l6l0l0l0l0l264l1106l0.4.2l6l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=9f1a6ca8782eeaef&biw=1280&bih=936).

Comment: 'street food' sounds somewhat infelicitous. 'food vendor' all by itself is natural and sufficient. 'Vendor' already gives the connotation of informal.

Comment: @Mitch agree. I was just sharing what came to my mind.

Comment: @Mitch: "Street food" doesn't sound infelicitous to me. Searching for the phrase "street food" [gives](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22street+food%22) an estimated 8 million articles, and even a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_food) by that name.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: yes, I agree. what I should have said is that 'street food -vendor-' sounds 'off'. I still find that 'street food' is mildly strange, but that the triple is much more 'off'.

Comment: As I said, this depends on where you are. In Mexico, for instance, "street food" does not have a reputation for sanitation; in Kuala Lumpur, I wouldn't worry about it. But of course they don't call it "street food" there very much.

Answer (score 4):

Those familiar with South-East Asia might call it a *makan stall*.

Comment: @JasperLoy: I know.

Answer (score 4):

Like almost everything involved with popular food, terms for places like this are intensely local. In Singapore they used to be called *Hawker Centres*, and there are several other terms now for modern variations on Lee Kuan Yew's original idea of rounding up the street food vendors and putting them all in one **sanitary** place.

In Malaysia this might well be *Pasar Malam*, or *Pasar Minggu*; in Indonesia it might be *Rumah Makan*, and there are lots more terms that I don't know because I haven't been there.

Comment: Are any of those English words?

Comment: You tell me.
_Hawker_ is from the English verb _hawk_, and _Centre_ is from the Latin _centrum_ through English; _Pasar_ is originally from Arabic, cognate to English _Bazaar_; _Minggu_ is originally from Latin _Dominus_, through Portuguese _Domingo_ to Malay, where it means _Sunday_. _Rumah, Malam,_ and _Makan_ are Malay words, meaning _house, night,_ and _eat,_ respectively. All can be used  as phrases in English; I've heard'em.

Comment: Hah! Nice explanations. I also would say that the answer to the question does not need to be an English word, depending on the locale of the market. +1

Comment: Are these general terms or do they refer to one specific place? I mean, is, e.g. "Pasar Malam" a term that is applied to one particular place where vendors are selling, as a proper name, or are there many "pasar malams" scattered about? But in any case, I don't think any of the terms you mentioned would be recognized outside of those specific places.

Answer (score 3):

Among other words, I usually go with ***kiosk:*** A small open-fronted hut or cubicle from which newspapers, refreshments, tickets, etc., are sold.

Answer (score 0):

***Street Food Market*** is the closest term that is not specific to a particular location.  I used to work in the city I think your picture is in, and that is the general term we used in English.

Answer (score 0):

They can also be known as "Stands"

Taco Stand, Fruit Stand, Hotdog Stand, Popsicle Stand are some of the most-common, even idiomatic examples.